# Do I need to disable TIWorker.exe and respective TaskSheduler task in Windows Server 2016

Tags: scheduled-task, windows-registry, task-scheduler

We had previously been disabling the following tasks in our AWS instances to keep our load balancer from killing them when these tasks tried to run. TIWORKER.exe was the large colpurt for our 2012R2 servers. After taking a look at the the TaskScheduler section of an out of the box instance of 2016, there are no tasks like there are in 2012. Should I be worried about it? Do I need to disable it anymore.
Thanks.

**Heres the stuff we were disabling**

```
schtasks /Change /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Idle Maintenance" /Disable
schtasks /Change /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Maintenance Configurator" /Disable
schtasks /Change /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Manual Maintenance" /Disable
schtasks /Change /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" /Disable

#Adds a registry key to prevent Windows Maintenance tasks from running. 
Write-Host "Adding registry key to prevent Windows Maintenance tasks from running." 
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\Maintenance' -Name MaintenanceDisabled -PropertyType DWord -Value 1 -Force
```

Comment: TIWorker is the truated installer, which is used for installing as part of installing updates.  Are you sure you really want to disable it?

Comment: Yes, we have rules setup in our cloud environment for our short-term instances that if the CPU goes over a certain amount kill the instance and start a larger one.  Since we are deploying monthly images we don't need to patch in the environment.

Comment: @Maz Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Solx I ended up not disabling it for 2016, didn't see any issues.